# How can I write longs to a binary file in C++?

Tags: c++, file, io, binaryfiles

I have an array of longs, and I want to write each element into a binary file. I know that you use `write()` to write to a binary, but `write()` accepts two arguments: a pointer to a char array (the buffer), and a number. Since I have an array of longs, I wasn't able to write using `write()`. I even tried passing a pointer to the long int array directly into the first argument, but it produced a compiler error.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
long* arr = new long [999999];

// imaginary code that fills arr with data

file.write(arr,1000000);
```

**How can I write my array of longs into a binary file?** I've considered somehow converting the longs into chars, but I doubt that would work, and there might be a loss in precision when converting between the data types. In addition, when I compile the code, the compiler error left this note: "`no known conversion for argument 1 from 'long int*' to 'const char*'`".

Thanks for helping.

Comment: _"Since I have an array of longs, I cannot write using write()"_ Why not?

Comment: _"I've considered somehow converting the longs into chars, but I very highly doubt that will work"_ Why not?

Comment: Curious what research you performed as this has been a common technique for some 40 years.

Comment: Well, I did specify that I tried to brute force it and it didn't work. Brute forcing it for me means doing just that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's exactly what you should do:

```
const size_t N = 999999;
long* arr = new long[N];
file.write((const char*)arr, sizeof(long)*N);
```

This [reinterprets your array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) of `long`s as a simple sequence of bytes (i.e. `char`s), and writes that sequence to the file.

Comment: Ah... so I should just typecast?

Comment: Well, I said I passed the array **directly** into the argument without typecasting. Anyways, you solved my problem, so thanks!

Comment: @C.He: "Brute forcing" is casting, as shown. I would not describe implicit conversions as forcing anything, hence the cast was required.

Comment: Keep in mind if you use this data file on two systems with different CPU (that differ in byte-order) you will have problems. If you want it to be portable, store them using htonl() and when you read them use ntohl()